# Firebase child_added event returns Invalid path error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

My firebase is structured like this:

```
Root -> micra -> Object1 -> Key : Value
                         -> Key : Value
                         -> Key : Value
                         -> Key : Value

              -> Object2 ->
                         ->
                         ->
                         ->
```

and so on. I'm trying to listen to the `child_added` event on the `micra` object like:

```
var micraRef = new Firebase('http://<myfirebase>.firebaseio.com/micra');
micraRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot); });
```

It looks simple like its supposed to work, but I keep getting this dirty error:

```
Uncaught Error: Firebase.DataSnapshot.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any thoughts could be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: The error says that you are passing an object into the URL instead of a string. Your example here does not include the offending code.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesnt include the offending code because this seems to be a recurring bug in AngularFire which no one seems to address